# Can't access OpenShift console on http://ip:8443

Tags: docker, localhost, centos7, openshift-origin

I've installed OpenShift Version 3 on CentOS7.
I followed the official documentation:
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/install/prerequisites.html#configuring-docker-storage

method 1 (Docker):
https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#installation-methods

I chose to install OpenShift in a Docker Container.
The last commmand I had to do was this one: 
I'm launching the server in a Docker container using images from Docker Hub.:

```
$ docker run -d --name "openshift-origin" --net=host --privileged \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /tmp/openshift:/tmp/openshift \
openshift/origin start
```

This command:

- starts OpenShift listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0:8443),
- **starts the web console listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0:8443),**
- launches an etcd server to store persistent data, and
- launches the Kubernetes system components.

  ```
  $ sudo docker ps

  CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

  d3f023085328        openshift/origin    "/usr/bin/openshift    2 days ago          Up 2 days                               openshift-origin
  ```

Now I was able to do:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it openshift-origin bash
```

So I can access openshift in my container. I can create projects and apps but the building-state is always pending.
I'm not able to visit `https://publicip:8443/console`. Someone who can help me? The OpenShift-page loads for a second (when i'm going http://publicip:8443) but than I get a redirect_url to 10.0.0.x:8443. My master-config looks like this: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/test/old-start-configs/v1.0.0/config/openshift.local.config/master/master-config.yaml. What do I have to change?

url: `https://10.0.0.x:8443/oauth/authorize?client_id=openshift-web-console&response_type=token&state=%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F10.0.0.x%3A8443%2Fconsole%2Foauth`

EDIT:

```
docker run -d --name "origin" \
        --privileged --pid=host --net=host \
        -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw \
        -v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes \
        openshift/origin start
```

Comment: Do you use the free version? Because https is only supported under the bronze and upwards plan.

Comment: Yes, but I can't find the information about the support of it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?: https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-rhel-centos.html

Comment: Not really, I think RHC is for OpenShift V2, isn't it? And don't we use oc for OpenShift V3?

Comment: Wow, this is embarassing (for me and for Red Hat). Yeah you are right, this is the documentation vor OS v2.2. But here is the real deal (; https://docs.openshift.org/latest/whats_new/overview.html#

Comment: Thanks, but normally the console would available after the installation of Docker and OpenShiftV3. So the question is still unanswered :)

Comment: What happens if you curl https://localhost:8443 from the command line of your host (inside and outside the container?)

Comment: It gives a blank line back and after that I got my prompt back

Comment: Did you try using a Vagrantfile for installing? I dont know if this accounts for CentOS7 but it says here: https://github.com/openshift/origin:  Important!: Docker on non-RedHat distributions (Ubuntu, Debian, boot2docker) has mount propagation PRIVATE, which breaks running Origin inside a container. Please use the Vagrant or binary installation paths on those distributions.https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc#develop-on-virtual-machine-using-vagrant

Comment: I did not use it for CentOS. My OpenShift is running inside a container and it's working because I can create projects and apps inside it. But I can't access the web console. (documentation says: All static assets required to run the web console are served from the openshift binary)

Comment: @lorenzvth7 Did you get this working? Was it just a firewall problem?  ie do you see anything if you run ```netstat -tpln | grep 8443``` ? I'm getting a similar problem but it's not listening on 8443 at all for some reason.  Although I had it work a few months ago, which is curious

Comment: @JoelPearson Don't really remember it. I went over to the advanced installation which worked well. Now I tried it again for you and it seemed to work for me (seeing the webconsole etc). I have written the command I executed to start the container in my question. Hope it helps.
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2828/openshift`(had to perform the netstat as root)

Comment: @lorenzvth7 Thanks, I figured out my problem, I was trying to specify a proxy server with ```-e http_proxy=http://proxy:port``` but apparently that causes 8443 not to bind properly.  ```-e HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:port``` make it work properly.
I was using the same start command as you (with the addition of the proxy) from https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. In my case I can access the web console. But could not login to it. I have an user in openshift who has cluster-admin rights. But when I try to login using that creds, it redirects to an error page(empty error). Not: The openshift cluster runs in an separate VM and I am trying to access the web console from my local machine.

Comment: @SujaiSivasamy Are you able to login in your terminal? (oc login..)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am wrong, but in order to be able to connect to the container on port 8443 using the host's ip, you need to publish this port on the host. This can be done in the docker run command by adding the argument -p 8443:8443

See https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: He specified "--net=host" which means the host machine's entire network stack is available to the container, so no ports need to be published

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, but got around it with an SSH tunnel.

Try executing the following:

```
ssh -gf -D 8443 <publicip> -N
```

And then visit the IP address you are being forwarded to after setting the SOCKS proxy on your browser to `localhost:8443`